# Load something on every CakePHP page

Tags: cakephp, controller

Is it possible to load something on every CakePHP page without having to add a request in every actions in every model? Just add it somewhere and it's done for all the pages?

Comment: Yes, but you need to be more specific what you want to do. You can add common elements to either controllers, models, and/or templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, Models do not have actions. Controllers have actions.

You can load data in all controllers by using `AppController::beforeFilter()`

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->set('something', $foobar);
    }
}
```

You can also load view stuff on all pages in the layout file.